# Laravel create eloquent object from JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I have this JSON object at client side:

[image]

I send that ajax JSON object to Controller like:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: url,
           data: {sToken: token.id, reference: r, newserials: jsonObj},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(data)
           { ... ... etc.
```

Then at Controller I grab it with:

```
$newserials = $request->newserials;
```

What I need now is to convert `$newserials` to eloquent object so I want to use `$newserials` like:

```
foreach ($newserials as $new) {

$serial = $new->serial;
$pin = $new->pin;

}
```

**So how I can convert JSON to eloquent and use in the way above?**

The app is live and I cant test this that's why I ask for help for this trivial questions. Sorry about that.

UPDATE:
I send newserial as a string:

var newserials = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

the rest of code is as you suggest:

```
$newserials = json_decode(json_encode($request->newserials));
```

but now I got error:

Trying to get property of non object at foreach loop!

[image]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel automatically `json_decode`s the input from json requests, but it decodes objects as associative arrays instead of objects. If you really want an object, you'll want to just encode and decode again.

```
$newserials = json_decode(json_encode($request->newserials));
```

Note, however, that this is just a plain PHP `stdClass` object, which I'm assuming is really all you need. This is not an Eloquent model.

Comment: I send newserials as a string, so I make var newserials = JSON.stringify(jsonObj); ... and now I got error at foreach loop - trying to get propery of non object... How to solve that, please help

Comment: @AleksPer You'll need to update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: As you can see at the image : 'newserials' => array(array('serial' => 'E1768520/1', 'pin' => 'HRYJ')),

Comment: @AleksPer I ran this code `$r = array(array('serial' => 'E1768520/1', 'pin' => 'HRYJ')); $newserials = json_decode(json_encode($r)); echo $newserials[0]->serial;` and it worked just fine. Can you put `var_export($request->newserials);` before the json_decode and `dd($newserials);` after the json_decode and post the results?

Comment: @AleksPer I'm guessing your error is somewhere else. That output shows the correct data. `$newserials` is an array. It has one item that is an object, with the correct properties. You'll need to track down where the error is coming from in your code.